# How to override node.js core module?

Tags: node.js

I would like to use https://github.com/isaacs/readable-stream instead of core node.js `stream` module. However I would like other third-party modules to use it as well - is it possible to override core module at runtime?

For example I would like this code:

```
var stream = require('stream');
```

to return `readable-stream` library instead of core `stream` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following module (`mock-require.js`):

```
'use strict';

var Module = require('module');
var assert = require('assert');

var require = function require(path) {
    assert(typeof(path) == 'string', 'path must be a string');
    assert(path, 'missing path');

    var _this = this;
    var next = function() { return Module.prototype.require.next.apply(_this, arguments); };

    console.log('mock-require: requiring <' + path + '> from <' + this.id + '>');

    switch (path) {
        case 'stream':
            // replace module with other
            if (/\/readable-stream\//.exec(this.filename)) {
                // imports from within readable-stream resolve into original module
                return next('stream');
            } else {
                return next('readable-stream');
            }

        case 'events':
            // mock module completely
            return {
                EventEmitter: next('eventemitter2').EventEmitter2,
                usingDomains: false
            }

        case 'hello/world :)':
            // name can be anything as well
            return { hello: 'world!' };

        default:
            // forward unrecognized modules to previous handler
            console.log(path);
            return next(path);
    }
};

require.next = Module.prototype.require;

Module.prototype.require = require;

module.exports = {};
```

You need to require it once somewhere in your project, so `require()` is properly intercepted. You are also free to provide some flexible API to registering/unregistering mock modules (something like `require.filter(/^foo\/\d+/, function(path) { return { boo: 'hoo' }; });` — I hadn't bothered with it yet.

Usage example then is as follows:

```
'use strict';

require('./mock-require');

require('util');

console.log(require('hello/world :)'));
console.log(require('events'));
console.log(require('stream'));
```

Comment: I've fixed import error for `stream`, it was because of circular dependency, because `readable-stream` depends on `stream`, which itself resolved into `readable-stream` even within `readable-stream`. I've fixed it to resolve into different modules depending on where it's called from.